# set the xlim in when xaxis is timedelta

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having a little problem to set the `xlim` when I'm working with a timedelta.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import datetime

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

df = pd.DataFrame({'deltaTime': [0, 10, 20, 30], 'length': [0.002, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003]})
df['deltaTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['deltaTime'], unit='m')

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%M'))


ax1.set_xlim([datetime.time(0,0,0), datetime.time(1,0,0)])


ax1.plot_date(df['deltaTime'], df['length'], marker='o', markersize=5, linestyle='-')

plt.show()
```

This line seems not to work:

```
ax1.set_xlim([datetime.time(0,0,0), datetime.time(1,0,0)])
```

Is there something similar that I could use in order to get my limits set when I'm using pandas timedelta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

matplotlib [plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html) takes x and y that are the datetime objects and not timedelta (duration) objects. you can convert the timedelta objects to datetime objects as shown below (by adding a date object with timedelta). hope this is what you were looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import datetime


fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

df = pd.DataFrame({'deltaTime': [0, 10, 20, 30], 'length': [0.002, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003]})

df['deltaTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['deltaTime'], unit='m')

df['start_date'] =  pd.Timestamp('20171204')+ df['deltaTime']
print df['start_date']

ax1.plot_date(df['start_date'], df['length'], marker='o', markersize=5, linestyle='-')                            
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%M'))

ax1.set_xlim(['20171204 00:10:00', '20171204 00:30:00'])

plt.show()
```

results in

```
0   2017-12-04 00:00:00
1   2017-12-04 00:10:00
2   2017-12-04 00:20:00
3   2017-12-04 00:30:00
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

[image]